# How Can I see all of the elements stored in my ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to store a list of created players to an array list.
I have two questions.

1. From looking at my code, Is my list being overwritten each time I add a new player?
2. How do I see all of the players that have been stored in this arrayList?

If you guys have ANY feedback or tips for me that would be amazing(Could I be using a different data structure or list or would something like a map be better for this) 
Kind of a novice at this.
Happy new year

Thanks in advance

```
package p;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PlayerData {

    private String name = "";
    private String age = "";
    private String player_id = "";
    private String agent_id = "";
    private double valuation;
    private String status;
    private String position;

    public PlayerData(String n, String a, String id, String aid, Double val, String sts, String pos) {

        name = n;
        age = a;
        player_id = id;
        agent_id = aid;
        valuation = val;
        status = sts;
        position = pos;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getPlayer_id() {
        return player_id;
    }

    public void setPlayer_id(String player_id) {
        this.player_id = player_id;
    }

    public String getAgent_id() {
        return agent_id;
    }

    public void setAgent_id(String agent_id) {
        this.agent_id = agent_id;
    }

    public double getValuation() {
        return valuation;
    }

    public void setValuation(double valuation) {
        this.valuation = valuation;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void printData() {

        // System.out.println("Name\tAge\tPlayer Id\t Agent Id\tValuation\t Status\t
        // position");
        System.out.println(name + "\n" + age + "\n" + player_id + "\n" + agent_id + "\n" + valuation + "\n" + status
                + "\n" + position);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Plz enter Name : ");
        String name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Plz enter age : ");
        String age = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Plz enter Player_id : ");
        String player_id = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Plz enter agent_id : ");
        String agent_id = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Plz enter status : ");
        String status = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Plz enter position : ");
        String position = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Plz enter valuation : ");
        Double valuation = input.nextDouble();

        ArrayList<PlayerData> Player = new ArrayList<PlayerData>();
        Player.add(new PlayerData(name, age, player_id, agent_id, valuation, status, position));

        System.out.println("\nPlayer Details entered: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < Player.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println(Player.get(i).getName());
            System.out.println(Player.get(i).getAge());
            System.out.println(Player.get(i).getPlayer_id());
            System.out.println(Player.get(i).getAgent_id());
            System.out.println(Player.get(i).getValuation());
            System.out.println(Player.get(i).getStatus());
            System.out.println(Player.get(i).getPosition());
            System.out.println(Player.iterator());

        }
        System.out.println(Player.toArray().toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1 From looking at my code, Is my list being overwritten each time I add a new player?

You only add one `PlayerData` object to the `ArrayList`.

> How do I see all of the players that have been stored in this arrayList?

You already do, you only have one player in the ArrayList, example with foreach:

```
    List<PlayerData> players = new ArrayList<PlayerData>();
    System.out.println("\nPlayer Details entered: ");
    for (PlayerData player: players) {
        System.out.println(player.getName());
        System.out.println(player.getAge());
        System.out.println(player.getPlayer_id());
        System.out.println(player.getAgent_id());
        System.out.println(player.getValuation());
        System.out.println(player.getStatus());
        System.out.println(player.getPosition());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding just one player. If you would like to add multiple players you should do it inside a while loop. Then you are able to add multiple records into your arrayList. But you need to remember that you need a condition to exit this while loop.

```
public class Main {

    public static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player player = null;
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter player id: ");
            String id = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter player name: ");
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            player = new Player(id, name);
            players.add(player);
            if (players.size() == 2) break;
        }

        System.out.println(players);
    }

    public static class Player {
        private String _id;

        private String _name;

        public Player(String id, String name) {
            _id = id;
            _name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Player{" +
                    "_id='" + _id + '\'' +
                    ", _name='" + _name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for you're help. I was wondering how could I store  and add players whenever I want? This seems to create two players and then remove it when I try to make two more.

Comment: or am I totally Wrong?

Comment: @KeithNolo you're right, as you can see there is an `if(players.size() == 2) break;` it means when you will add two players quit the while loop and exit the whole program. You can manipulate the conditions however you want, also if you do not want to lose the players you already saved, would be good to store them somewhere. In this case is good to have a database, or if you do not want to play around with database you can use a file where players will be saved. Let's say you will store each player as a line in a file. Then you can read lines of that file and split properties and put to list.